# Запуск по крону url

Tags: cron

Будет ли крон такое запускать?

```
/usr/bin/php -f http://site.su/service/update/
```

Comment: Ээммм, а что должно произойти?

Comment: Ну по этому url все скрипты прописаны. Я не могу указать ссылку прямую на php файл

Comment: Странный способ. Как можно по http получить php код, если крону нужен путь к файлу на текущем сервере?

Comment: Ну такой вот способ. Не буду вашу голову засорять почему так. Можно ил url по крону запустить?

Answer (score 1):

url -- нет. Но Вы написали строку, в которой запускается php. Не вижу причины, по которой это не будет работать. Если нужны переменные среды, позаботьтесь о них специально.
Но разумеется всё это при условии, что с командной строки оно работает.

Answer (score 1):

а кто мешает сделать где то так

```
curl адрес-скрипта | /usr/bin/php
```

Но только скрипт лучше обозвать без расширения php, а то сервер будет его исполнять. С другой стороны, может быть это и нужно, тогда пусть.
Но будет ещё лучше - положить все это в .sh файл и уже его запускать кроном.